# How to query 2 columns from 1 table and another column from a second table

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm using MySql on ubuntu if that matters.

I need to query the name of the employes from the Employes table, along with the name of their department heads.

Here is what my tables look like:

[image]

To make my question clearer, I need to query the names from `Employes`, and somehow link the DIR # from the Dept table (20,30 and 40) to display who is associated to those numbers in the `Employes` table.

I've tried this query so far:

```
select ENOM e, DIR d from Employes e, Departements d where e.ENO=d.DIR;
```

But this only returns me the names of the employes and their department number, not their head of departments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select emp.employee_name, d.department_head from employee emp,
 department d where emp.employee_id = d.employee_id;
```

Comment: It's better to rewrite with JOIN

Comment: thats not solving the problem Geronimo asked, as far is i understood

Answer (score 0):

First select the employes, join to the department table with the department number and finally do another join from the department table to the employee table - but this time with the DIR (director) column - like:

```
       SELECT E.ENOM
             ,D.DNOM
             ,Head.ENOM AS DepartmentHead
         FROM Employes E
   INNER JOIN Departements D
           ON E.DNO    = D.DNO
   INNER JOIN Employes Head
           ON D.DIR    = Head.ENO
```